# django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: django_site while running pytest even though django_site exists

Tags: django, database, unit-testing, pytest

I am using openedx project and I want to run all unit tests. Even though the django_site table exists in my database when I run pytest I get the error:
`django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: django_site`
The database info is following:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': TEST_ROOT / "db" / "cms.db",
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True,
    },
}
```

I am using this command to run the tests: `pytest --create-db --ds=lms.envs.test --exitfirst openedx/core/`.
What can I do to fix this?